# How to bind $index inside a function in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have repeated a div by using angular js `ng-repeat`

```
<div ng-repeat="exampleData in example">
<input type="text" id="{{ $index }}percentage"/>
<button type="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitted('{{ $index }}fromHours')">Submit</button>
</div>
```

So, when I click on submit button submitted method will be called with input feilds id passed as parameter in it,

Please take a look at the js code below :

```
$scope.submitted = function(percentage){
console.log($('#'+percentage).val());
}
```

Now when I use the parameter and print its value I'm getting error, Saying

```
Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #{{ $index }}percentage
```

How should I get the exact value of the input type with {{ $index }}percentage as ID

I have written $index to have the unique id as the text box will be repeated many times.

Please help, thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the expressions when you pass an index to a `ng-click` function.

```
ng-click="submitted($index + 'fromHours')">
```

Comment: @Harish nice. make sure to check as right answer if this helped

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<input type="text" ng-id="$index + 'percentage'"/>
```

verify in the HTML if this value is properly populated.

Same is applicable to button as well

```
<button type="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitted($index + 'fromHours')">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" ng-id="$index + 'percentage'"/>

<button type="btn btn-success" ng-click="submitted('$index + 'fromHours')">Submit</button>
```

Do it this way.